# Objects in animation moving at different speeds on the same keyframe

Tags: animation

I have a crown that is composed of a gold frame and pearls. The gold frame is one object and the pearls are a second object. I hit "a" in order to select both the crown and the pearls. Then I added two key frames one of the current location then one 10 frames later of the crown rotating and moving downwards (like it is falling through the air). However, in frames 1 and 10 the pearls are in the correct location but during frames 2-9 the pearls move at a different speed and follow a different path then the crown so they don't look like they are connected to the crown when it is falling. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could *[parent](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting#Parenting_objects)* the pearls to the crown, so that they follow the crown without being animated.

To do this, select the pearls and then the crown (so that the crown is active), and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. Now you only have to animate the crown.

---

As for the reasons why the objects are out of sync in the first place, my first guess is that the origins are not in the same place.